# mobilechelonian fails to draw in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I tried mobilechelonian module to use a turtle in python jupyter notebook in different clouds (google collab or a server available for my school). On both servers, the module can be installed or is already installed:

```
%pip install mobilechelonian
```

yields (three first lines):

```
Requirement already satisfied: mobilechelonian in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets>=7.0.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mobilechelonian) (7.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: IPython in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mobilechelonian) (7.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from IPython->mobilechelonian) (2.7.2)
```

I just copied and pasted the demo code in a cell:

```
from mobilechelonian import Turtle
t = Turtle()
t.speed(5)
colours=["red","blue","yellow","brown","black","purple","green"]

t.penup(); t.left(90); t.forward(200);t.right(90);t.pendown()
for i in range (0,18):
    t.pencolor(colours[i%7])
    t.right(20)
    t.forward(50)

t.right(180)
t.home()
```

The results is no the [waited colored polygon](https://github.com/takluyver/mobilechelonian) but an cell with the output:

```
Turtle()
```

Thank you for suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, the notebook displays the drawing when launched from a classical jupyter notebook  and fails when launched from jupyterlab.